# Read Java object as DataSet in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark-dataset

I have a HDFS path which contains data written by Java object say Obj1, I want to read this path in my spark Scala code and read it as a DataSet of Obj1.

One way to do this will be to read the HDFS path, apply a map on it to create a new Scala object corresponding to Obj1. 
Is there a simpler way to do this, as we know in java we can do something like :

```
Dataset<Obj1> obj1DataSet = sparkSession.read().parquet("path").as(Encoders.bean(Obj1.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows :

```
val obj1Encoder: Encoder[Obj1] = Encoders.bean(classOf[Obj1])
val objDataSet : Dataset[Obj1] = sparkSession.read.parquet("hdfs://dataPath/").as(obj1Encoder)
```